# Deleted some apk files - but the apps are still there after reboot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, clockworkmod-recovery

This seems really weird to me.

I followed the instructions given here

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=835861

and deleted the apk files of some stock applications like Layar. I also removed the odex files if I could find them.

Strangely, even after wiping the cache and a reboot, I can still run the apps from my launcher.

Samsung Galaxy S with CWM 3.2

Comment: Have you checked that apk file exists after reboot or not?

Comment: try browsing `/system/app` using root explorer and delete from there. Then reboot.

Comment: @SachinShekhar yes, the apk file doesn't exist any more in the folder /system/app

Comment: @ Web-E that's what I did at the beginning in order to get it deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some vendors set up their phones to reinstall system applications at boot in case they go missing.  Try finding a directory that contains a copy of the APK that's used to reinstall it, and delete it from there.

A simple alternative solution is to freeze the unwanted apps rather than uninstalling them.  Titanium Backup and Link2SD can help you with that (both require root).  In ICS+, there's also a user-accessible mechanism to deactivate apps from the settings menu.

Comment: Solved it: For some of the installed apk files, there seems to exist a copy in the folder /data/app . Even though the files there follow a different naming scheme, it is possible to pick out the corresponding ones.      After deleting /data/app/com.sec.android.app.samsungapps-2.apk (and after wiping the cache) the app finally disappeared from my launcher.

Comment: Ah, good! These may have been auto-updated versions of the original apps installed in /system/app. -- Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 0):

Clear dalvik-cache, and you are done.